# C Major with F# transpose to D major

Tags: theory, accidentals, transposition

I have C major with F# in it. If I want to transpose it to D major, do I just raise F# two steps up? So G#? I am a little confused about transposing with accidentals involved.... Should I follow the key signature of the key (ignore the accidentals, in this case F# just becomes G because there is not G# in the D Major) or I just raise everything up two half tones?

Comment: When I posted my answer, I overlooked the significance of the question "should I ... ignore the accidentals, in this case F# just becomes G because there is not G# in the D Major ... ?"  Of course, there's no F# in C major, either (or, more precisely, there is no F sharp in the C major _scale;_ keys can use notes that are outside the scale).  I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 7):

So, you have a song that's in C major, there's an F# i.e. raised F note somewhere in the song, and you want to know how to handle the F# note when transposing the whole song up to D major. The distance from C to D is one (1) whole tone, and two (2) semitones. Or a "major second".

## To get the SOUND right

To get the sound transposed right, move all notes up by two semitones, whichever way you do it. On the guitar you could put a capo on the 2nd fret. Or you could move all fingerings up by two frets. Or use a transposing instrument and play normally. Or speed up the tape or turntable by 12.2%. To get the sound transposed, you don't necessarily need to worry about theory i.e. how to talk about the notes.

## To get the THEORY right

In our commonly used music theory i.e. way of talking about music, pitches are called by letter names: C, D, E, F, G, A, B, and in the most common case, there are assumed to be seven different notes i.e. scale degrees per octave in a scale. Each of the seven letter-named scale degrees can be altered by raising i.e. "sharpening" or lowering i.e. "flatting". But each letter name is used by one scale degree at a time. (There are types of music that use *eight* different scale degrees simultaneously, and those kinds of music are awkward to talk about using this seven-note theory i.e. way of talking.) In songs in C major, the seven note names for scale degrees are, in the default basic setting, as follows:

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  C  D  E  F  G  A  B
```

In a situation where you have the F# note, the scale's note number 4 i.e. F is temporarily raised

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  C  D  E  F# G  A  B
```

In the key of D major, the scale degree letter names start from D, and they are, by default in their basic assumed position, as follows

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  D  E  F# G  A  B  C#
```

Being "in C" means that your scale degree 1 i.e. tonic is C. Being "in D" means that your scale degree 1 is D. When you transpose the song from C to D, all the scale degree numbers and their modifications stay the same, but the scale is moved to start from a different letter name. What was scale degree 4 in C major, is scale degree 4 in D major, in the transposed song.

And here comes the important bit:

### what was a raised scale degree 4 in C major, is still a raised scale degree 4 in D major, in the transposed song

So the scale degrees, in the part of the song that has scale degree 4 raised, in D major, are the following:

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  D  E  F# G# A  B  C#
```

As an exercise, let us transpose the song to F# major, which has the following default scale degrees:

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  F# G# A# B  C# D# E#
```

During the moment in the song where there was the F# note in the original C major key, the scale number 4 becomes B#:

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  F# G# A# B# C# D# E#
```

Then as one more example, let us transpose the song to F major. In F major, the default scale degrees are:

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  F  G  A  Bb C  D  E
```

The original C major's F# note becomes B, when we raise the Bb:

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  F  G  A  B  C  D  E
```

Theory fans may notice that the modified scale, with the raised degree 4 is the scale of the Lydian mode, and this last example scale would be called the F Lydian scale. (If the song keeps this scale degree "geometry" from beginning to end, and if it has degree 1 as the tonic i.e. home note all the time, then you could say it is in the Lydian mode.)

By popular request, let's see what happens if we raise a scale degree that was already sharp. If the original song in C had a G# note, which is very common in songs in C or Am (you need a G# for an E major chord, which is a dominant for Am), how would it transpose to the key of F#? For example Yesterday, in C, the line "all my troubles seemed so far away" would use these notes:

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
LETTER NAME  :  C  D  E  F# G# A  B
```

What happens if we transpose that to F# major?

```
SCALE DEGREE :  1  2  3  4  5   6  7
LETTER NAME  :  F# G# A# B# C## D# E#
```

So, we get a B sharp and a C *double-sharp*. On a piano, you play the B# note with the same key as a C note, and the C## with the same key as a D. B# is said to be *enharmonic* with C, and C## is enharmonic with D. They're *enharmonic equivalents*. Guitarists might just shrug and move their hand along the fretboard.

Comment: Great explanation, although I think the Lydian bit is a red ferret! +1.

Comment: I was hoping this (excellent) answer would point out, for those who need it pointed out, that this can result in some "funny notes." If it had been, say, the 2nd scale degree that got raised—say, the C Major original had a D# in it—then in F# Major that would be a G *double sharp*. Similarly, if that 2nd scale degree were lowered, then in F# Major it would simply be G natural. It's easy to get the wrong end of "sharps make things higher and flats make things lower"; in this discussion, they just happen to be part of the "names" of the pitches in a scale.

Answer (score 3):

Every note should be raised a major second. So the F# will become G#. As you say, G# is not in the key of D major, but neither is F# in the key of C major. Both G# and F# bear the same relationship to their respective home keys.

Rather than think of transposition as moving from one key to another, it's helpful to think of it as moving up or down by a specific interval. From that point of view, it's more clear that every note is changed in exactly the same way. By doing so, the relationship between each note with every other note is preserved, and the music will sound exactly the same, except higher or lower by some interval.

Comment: @Cas It would be better for this answer to refer to the transposition as a major second than as two semitones.  After all, A flat is two semitones above F sharp, but it is not the correct result for the transposition in question.

Comment: @phoog good call.

Answer (score 3):

By transposing from key C to key D, you're moving all notes up by *one tone*. That means their letter names will be the next in the alphabetic name, except G will be called A in the new key.

Any accidentals attached will follow into the new key.

***BUT*** - since the new key D already contains two 'altered' notes, F♯ and C♯, E>F♯ and B>C♯, to retain the spacings of notes in a major key.

So, C>D. D>E. E>F(♯). F>G. G>A. A>B. B>C(♯). Any note in the *original* key that has an accidental attached will retain that accidental. So your F♯ in key C goes to G♯ in key D. It's moved up, as all other notes, by one tone.

Thinking intervals will work, but it's an onerous task. Better to think in terms of one tone, and next letter name. That way, the new G♯ can't be called A♭.

Comment: The method given in this answer is the correct one, as it gets the letter name correct (not just the pitch in equal temperament).

Comment: @RosieF temperament is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I ... ignore the accidentals, in this case F# just becomes G because there is not G# in the D Major ... ?

But there's no F♯ in C major, either!  The transposed note has to have the same relationship to the new key as the original note has to the old key.  If you start with a note that has an accidental, you should end with a note that has an accidental.

The simplest approach:  D is a major second above C, so every note in the transposition is a major second above the original note.

This means that the letter name increases by 1, so "F" becomes "G," and the new note must be two semitones higher than the original, so F♯ must become G♯.

Alternatively, if you're thinking about written music, you shift everything up by a second (so if the original note was on a line, the transposed note is on the space above, and if it was on a space, it's on the line above).  Then you just adjust the accidental if necessary, according to the change in key signature.

For example, imagine that you have a B♭ in your piece in C.  When you write it out in D, you write a C, but instead of the original ♭ accidental, you use ♮ because there is a C♯ in the key signature for D major whereas there is no accidental on B in the key of C.  By contrast, there's no F accidental in C major and no G accidental in D major, so the accidental doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

> I have C major with F# in it. If I want to transpose it to D major

You want to transpose.

Think in generic, relative terms, including in the starting key.

You are in `C` major. `F` is the fourth scale degree, `^4`, the subdominant. That tone is specifically sharp, `F#`, so you are using a *raised* subdominant, `#^4`.

Generically you are in a major key with a raised subdominant, `#^4`.

To transpose...

- set the tonic from `C` to `D`
- keep the mode set at major
- determine the `^4` subdominant is `G`
- raise the `G` to `G#`

...now you  are in `D` major with raised subdominant `G#`.

Considering the key signature and the raised subdominant the sharpened tones in the new key are `F#`, `C#`, and `G#`.

Regarding the answers that suggest thinking in terms on interval shifting all tones, I disagree. If you are actually working with major/minor keys, the whole point of transposition is to think in relative terms and just change tonic. From that perspective you are *not* just learning how to deal with two specific keys, you are learning how to deal *with any key.* Basically, your chord progressions and melodic intervals all become *relative motions* (like for example `ii V I`, `^2 ^4 ^3`, up `m3` down `m2`, etc.) and you only need to know the starting point, the tonic.